# Resources folder is not included in the JAR file when exporting it using Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

The resources folder `/src/main/resources` is marked as **Resources Root**, but is not included in the JAR file when building artifacts with Gradle of the project module.

[image: resources folder]

I tried including it in `build.gradle` but it is still not showing up. How can I modify the **Project Structure** to include the resources folder as well?

Comment: How are you building the jar. Are you using any special plugins?

Comment: @DanielScott I add the main module to the artifact category of the project structure. Then I build artifacts from the build menu. I don't use any special plugins except Gradle.

Comment: Please attach screenshot with Artifact configuration. Do you run "Build | Build Artifact" to create JAR?

Comment: @y.bedrov This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdfN4.png) of configurations, and yes, I run "Build | Build Artifact" to create JAR.

Comment: Please provide your `build.gradle` or a [mcve].

Comment: @Chriki I created a new simple project with the same problem. All files are included in the [repository](https://github.com/lashahub/myapp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run `./gradlew jar` on [your project](https://github.com/lashahub/myapp) mentioned in the comments, then the produced `build/libs/MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file contains the `directories.txt` file from `src/main/resources` as expected. So the Gradle setup is correct.

It rather sounds that your IntelliJ IDEA project is not configured properly. You should not manually tamper with the project settings but instead let the IntelliJ Gradle plugin take care of configuring the project. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import_project_start)’s how to properly import the project into IntelliJ:

> 1. If no project is currently opened in IntelliJ IDEA, click **Open** on the welcome screen. Otherwise, select **File | Open** from the main menu.
>    If you have some custom plugins that require you to import your project from the IntelliJ IDEA model, press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd> and search for the **Project from Existing Sources** action.
> 2. In the dialog that opens, select a directory containing a Gradle project and click **OK**.
>    IntelliJ IDEA opens and syncs the project in the IDE.
>
> If you need to adjust the Gradle settings options, refer to [Gradle settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html).